# Cloud Storage - File's content type is showing as data when a image is Uploaded

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading images to Cloud Storage using the [Java Client Library](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#create-com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo-byte:A-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobTargetOption...-)   Images are uploaded to Bucket but when I am trying to access them, a Black screen is displaying in browser. So, I dug into this to check the type of the Image after it is uploaded into Cloud Storage.

I uploaded the image I downloaded from the cloud storage to 
[Check File Type .com](http://checkfiletype.com/)      and it is showing file type as **data** and MIME/TYPE as **application/octet-stream**  instead of **image**

[image]

So , I uploaded the original image of the same from my PC and it is perfectly showing the image type as **image/jpeg**

[image]

Here is the code I have written using the Java client library.

> HTML Form to handle the upload

```html
<form action="/through" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Uploading File through App Engine instances to cloud storage</h3>
<label>Enter Your Team Name</label><br>
<input type="text" name="TeamName" ><br><br> 
<label>Upload Team Logo</label><br>
<input type="file" name="teamLogo" required="required"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Team Logo">
</form>
```

> Java code to Upload the Image

```
InputStream input = request.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
  int read = input.read();
  while(read != -1) {
    byteArrayStream.write(read);
    read = input.read();
  }
catch (IOException e){
  //Handle Exception 
}

byte[] fileBytes = byteArrayStream.toByteArray();

Storage storage = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream credentialsStream = new FileInputStream("JSONFile");
        Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);
        storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId("myProjectID").build().getService();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, USER_NAME+"TeamLogo.jpg");
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("image/jpeg").build();
    Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, fileBytes);
```

Why Cloud Storage is not able to detect the type of image properly? It is having adverse effects on other parts of my application where I want to display the same images.

**UPDATE**

In Console for the same object, Content-Type is showing as **image/jpeg**

[image]

Comment: In the Google Console -> Storage -> Select Object. Far right click column click on the triple dots -> Edit Metadata. What does the metadata header for Content-Type show for this object?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley , As you suggested I searched for it and had taken a screenshot of the same and added as a update to the answer. It is showing Content-Type as **image/jpeg**

Comment: The Content-Type matches your java code. Your problem is not with the upload unless the length is wrong. Update your question on how you are accessing these image (the download and display part).

Comment: Download the object using the Google Cloud Console. Verify that the downloaded file matches byte for byte what was uploaded.

Comment: I think your problem is with ByteArrayOutputStream and the code that builds byteArrayStream.

Comment: What is the ideal way to convert the input stream to byte[] then ? Any suggestions from your side ?

Comment: First verify that your download does not match the upload.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley , I compared the byte arrays before uploading and byte array of the same object I downloaded from Cloud Storage. both are not same but their length is same

Comment: This means that your upload is corrupted. Your code that is extracting the HTML object upload is broken. I don't know what the problem is with your code but now you know where to debug.

Comment: Where is the image that you are trying to upload? Is it in a file?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
package com.example.storage;

import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    File fi = new File("source.jpg");
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("your-bucket", "imagen.jpg");
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("image/jpeg").build();
    Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath()));
    System.out.println(blob.getContentType());
  }
}
```

I got the following result on [CheckFileType](http://checkfiletype.com/):
[image]

Comment: Hi bro, Thanks for your reply. But in my case I am getting the file over net. I am not reading the bytes of the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploading a file to your local instance, and then moving it to the Cloud Storage, you can instruct your client app to directly upload the file to the Cloud Storage using [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload).

If you do need to get file to your local instance first (e.g. for some processing before uploading it), you can use:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];

while ((nRead = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
  buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}

buffer.flush();
```